# Listing filenames having timestamp

Tags: shell, unix, datetime-format, unix-timestamp

Hi I want to list filenames in a directory having timestamp in its file name.
For example:
gn_752_pos_id_n_00_000_9_20200331.dat.gz
gn_40006_dep_ip_c_qa_500_2_20200331_20200622T082432.dat.gz

So I want to get a list of files having timestamp format like '20200622T082432'.

I tried the following command but it didn't work.
find . -type f | xargs ls -l --time-style="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to glob files whose name contains the pattern:

```
8 digits T 6 digits
```

You can do that like this:

```
ls *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

In practice, that is rather unwieldy, so you might define an alias:

```
alias ts='ls *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]T[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*'
```

Then you can just use:

```
ts
```

Or, you might find that a less rigorous test requiring only a single digit either side of `T` is enough for most purposes:

```
ls *[0-9]T[0-9]*
```

You could also leverage a *"regular expression"* with a specific number of repetitions (i.e. 8 digits, T, 6-digits) like this `GNU find`:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}.*"
```